# Symfony 4 - Two entities in one form using doctrine, one entity has to insert before the other

Tags: php, symfony

I can't get the textarea to show up inside my form when combining two entities. No javascript please, I've seen the javascript method with collections.

The logic is, have a user add a title on a form, and then add text in a textarea. When user submits, a thread gets inputted using the title, and thread id is used to add a post to it (the textarea content).

Form example :

[image]

---

I believe this is enough to output it, if it's setup correctly via the 2 "type" classes.

```
{{ form_start(forum_thread_form) }}
   {{ form_widget(forum_thread_form) }}
{{ form_end(forum_thread_form) }}
```

---

Code :

Entities

***Thread.php***

```
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Account", inversedBy="forum_posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $account;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="forum_threads")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", mappedBy="thread")
     */
    private $posts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ## getters and setters.. some ommitted ##
        /**

     /*
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $posts
     */
    public function setPosts($posts): void
    {
        $this->posts = $posts;
    }
```

***Post.php***

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Account", inversedBy="forum_posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $account;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Thread", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $thread;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $content;

 ## GETTERS AND SETTERS, some ommitted ##
 /**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getThread()
{
    return $this->thread;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $thread
 */
public function setThread($thread): void
{
    $this->thread = $thread;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $content
 */
public function setContent($content): void
{
    $this->content = $content;
}
```

***PostType.php***

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Post::class,
        ));
    }
```

***ThreadType.php***

```
public function __construct(){
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class);

        $builder->add('content', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => PostType::class,
            'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Thread::class,
        ));
    }
```

***ForumController.php***

```
$forum_thread = new Thread();
$forum_thread_form = $this->createForm(ThreadType::class,$forum_thread);

        $forum_thread_form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($forum_thread_form->isSubmitted() && $forum_thread_form->isValid()) {
            $forum_thread = $forum_thread_form->getData();

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($forum_thread);
            $entityManager->flush();

        }

        $forum_thread_form = $forum_thread_form->createView();

        return $this->render('forum/threads.html.twig',compact('forum_thread_form'));
```

Comment: Could you please link your controller?

Comment: @ShaithyaKannan added the controller code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in ThreadType, change `content` to `posts`:

```
$builder->add('posts', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => PostType::class,
        'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
    ));
```

Then, change the code in your action:

```
$forum_thread = new Thread();
$post = new Post();
$forum_thread->setPosts([$post]);
$forum_thread_form = $this->createForm(ThreadType::class, $forum_thread);

$forum_thread_form->handleRequest($request);

if ($forum_thread_form->isSubmitted() && $forum_thread_form->isValid()) {
    $forum_thread = $forum_thread_form->getData();

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($post);
    $entityManager->persist($forum_thread);
    $entityManager->flush();

}
```

This works:

- by creating a new Post
- adding an array containing only the new Post created
- `getPosts` is used to populate the "posts" field of CollectionType with a new PostType

Comment: Technically this is the correct answer and it works, I ended up using a hybrid of this and a DTO.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use single formtype + DTO to make that form, and after a submit + validation just create those necessary entities from that DTO and persist + flush those to database.

Comment: When I use this method, and create the form in controller, do I do $this->createForm(ThreadType::class, $forum_thread) or without the $forum_thread? I'm assuming $forum_thread is no longer required since it's not binded to an entity.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your twig

```
{{ form_start(forum_thread_form) }}
   {{ form_row(forum_thread_form.title) }}
   {%  for contentField in forum_thread_form.posts %}
          {{ form_row(contentField.content) }}
   {%  endfor %}
{{ form_end(forum_thread_form) }}
```

Comment: This still didn't work, I had to set "mapped" to false in the ThreadType and then save the post separately in controller, couldn't do it one go. then output was simple, didn't have to do for statement.

Comment: @Darius Does this mean that you solved your problem?

Comment: Not yet, it doesn't validate required fields. So the method I found doesn't work correctly. I will try the DTO method answered by tarl above.